# How do I access paragraphs with the JSON API?

Tags: 8, paragraphs

With the JSON API module, I am trying to access paragraphs.  In the JSON object it does not allow me to access the nested paragraphs.

How would I go about accessing the paragraphs with the JSON API?

*****Update with Solution*****

1. In the api call you need to have the correct URL format:  `/jsonapi/{entity_type_id}/{bundle_id}[/{entity_id}]?_format=api_json`.  The key here is to add this at the end of your the URL for the api call:  `?include={name of paragraph}`.  For example:    `/jsonapi/node/page?_format=api_json&include=field_testing_json_api`
2. Once you have the correct API call, you need to go to the Drupal admin dashboard and go to `people/permissions` and under the `Paragraphs Type Permissions` section you need to grant access to `view content` to the specific paragraph you want the user to access.

Answer (score 5):

2 steps required :)

1. create the paragraph(s) by doing a POST request, and receiving the revision ID of the created paragraph,
2. update the parent entity by assigning the paragraphs' revision ids to the paragraph field (entity revision reference field).

---

**Step 1.**

```
jsonbody = {
    'data': {
        'type': 'paragraph--study_history',
        'attributes': {
            'parent_id': localStorage.getItem('uid'),
            'parent_type': 'user',
            'parent_field_name': 'field_study_history'
        },
        'relationships': {
            'field_school_ref': {
                'data': {
                    'type': 'node--school',
                    'id': this.reg_selectedUni['id']
                }
            }
        }
    }
};

return this.api.apiPost('/jsonapi/paragraph/study_history', {}, jsonbody)
```

We are using our custom service `api` (ApiService.ts) which has the `apiPost` function that does exactly what you'd imagine :) 
So the logic above should be easy to adapt to your own code.

Note that if you want to add more fields (text fields for example, you add them to the attributes section).

---

**Step 2.**
Here’s how we update the user, PATCH it to have the created “study history” paragraphs.

```
const jsonbody = {
    'data': {
        'type': 'user--user',
        'id': uuid,
        'relationships': {
            'field_study_history': {
                'data': [
                    {
                        'type': 'paragraph--study_history',
                        'id': schoolhist_info['data']['id'],
                        'meta': {
                            'target_revision_id': schoolhist_info['data']['attributes']['revision_id'],
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        'type': 'paragraph--study_history',
                        'id': unihist_info['data']['id'],
                        'meta': {
                            'target_revision_id': unihist_info['data']['attributes']['revision_id'],
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
};
return this.api.apiPatch(this.endpoint.getUsers + '/' + uuid, {}, jsonbody);
```

Where `this.endpoint.getUsers` is `/jsonapi/user/user`.
This should be enough to get it to work, else comment and I can update.

Comment: Yes, I can also access the the type, id, and meta with the json api module.  What I can't access and what I don't see in your answer are the paragraphs fields(for example title and body).  How would I access the  paragraphs fields?

Comment: Added the first part that should answer your need exactly, sorry, misread at first :)

Comment: This seems to cover posting new content, rather than accessing existing content. I've [added an answer that covers the latter](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/273648/how-do-i-access-paragraphs-with-the-json-api/312184#312184).

Answer (score 0):

Try using http://yourhost.local/jsonapi/paragraph/myparagraph

It is navigable through your browser http://yourhost.local/jsonapi

Answer (score 0):

### Situation

Assuming you have published content that uses Paragraphs, and you want to retrieve the Nodes AND the Paragraphs:

1. Ensure you have permissions set to allow anonymous users to view your specific Paragraph types
2. Try the query pattern in your browser:
   `/jsonapi/node/<entity_type>?filter[status]=1&include=<field_name>,<field2_name>`

To break it down:

`/jsonapi/node/<entity_type>` - the JSON API endpoint for a type of node

`?filter[status]=1` - only return published nodes

`&include=<field_name>,<field2_name>` - additionally include these fields

Note that you must explicitly request your paragraph fields by name.

If the fields are restricted to authenticated users only, you'll nee to include an API key via either the request header or in the URL as a query parameter:

`?api-key=<KEY>`

### Common issues

Depending on permissions, some data may appear in the JSON API response, but restricted fields may not. If a Paragraph field is restricted, you'll see this in the response:

```json
"item--<hash>": {
   "href": "https://www.mysite.com/jsonapi/paragraph/<paragraph_type>/<hash>" 
   "meta": {
      "rel": "item",
      "detail": "The current user is not allowed to GET the selected resource."
   }
}
```

If this happens, you may need your Drupal user's API key (see the [Key_auth module](https://www.drupal.org/project/key_auth))